# Confusion aws cloudwatch old agent vs unified cloudwatch agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I was going through the AWS cloudwatch documentation for Cloudwatch agents. 
So I came across the documentation which says:
Unified Cloud watch agent is recommended and it has support across all operating systems.
But for old Cloud watch agent(on the path to deprecation) documentation mentions that **"it supports the collection of logs from only servers running Linux".**

[image: CloudWatch Agent]

But when I went ahead in documentation in next section (for Old cloudwatch agent):
Documentation mentions that **"Using the CloudWatch Logs agent, you can publish log data from Amazon EC2 instances running Linux or Windows Server, and logged events from AWS CloudTrail. We recommend instead using the CloudWatch unified agent to publish your log data."**
[image: Previous Cloudwatch agent]

So I am confused regarding whether the old cloudwatch agent supports EC2 instances running Windows server or not?
Is there anything I am overlooking?
Or is it just a documentation error from AWS side?

Edit:

[Getting Started with CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_GettingStarted.html)- This link mentions: Old cloudwatch agent supports the collection of logs from only servers running Linux.

[Using old cloudwatch agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/UsePreviousCloudWatchLogsAgent.html) - This link mentions: Using the CloudWatch Logs agent, you can publish log data from Amazon EC2 instances running Linux or Windows Server, and logged events from AWS CloudTrail

Comment: Can you provide the links to these website?

Comment: @Marcin Links added in question.

Comment: Old agent is buggy in some cases, and looks like it's out of date. Recommend to use unified agent for collecting logs.

Comment: Did @ABoringAI answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the next section of "Using old cloudwatch agent", it listed the CloudWatch Logs agent prerequisites, it doesn't include windows server.

- Amazon Linux version 2014.03.02 or later. Amazon Linux 2 is not supported
- Ubuntu Server version 12.04, 14.04, or 16.04
- CentOS version 6, 6.3, 6.4, 6.5, or 7.0
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) version 6.5 or 7.0
- Debian 8.0

However, from the following URL it is clear that you can use cloudwatch logs (old cloudwatch agent) for windows server.

So, I believe cloudwatch logs (old cloudwatch agent) supports windows server.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartWindows2016.html

Answer (score 0):

Just was having some similar doubt.
The old cloudwatch logs is going to be deprecated

> [...] Recommended – The unified CloudWatch agent. It enables you to collect both logs and advanced metrics with one agent. It offers support across operating systems, including servers running Windows Server.  [...]

And the old one as you say, it does not support collecting metrics from windows servers:

> [...] The older CloudWatch Logs agent, which supports the collection of logs from only servers running Linux. [...]

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_GettingStarted.html